# Can Oracle golden gate adapter read trail file which generated by Extract or Pump process?

Tags: ogg, oracle-golden-gate

I am researching OGG, Can Oracle golden gate adapter read trail file which generated by Extract or Pump process? Most example I can find is OGG adapter works for replication process on delivery server, I just wanna apply the adapter whatever via plat file, jms or java api on extract or pump process directly.

Answer (score 1):

The trail file is just an intermediate internal Oracle GoldenGate format which is used to store the data. The source is processed by the Extract process.

The **Extract** process can read the data from:

- a database transaction log,
- a JMS Queue or a flat file (through GoldenGate for Application Adapters)

The **Extract** process produces as output:

- trail files (to be processed by Replicat processes)
- XML files
- SQL files

If you set a **Trail file** as the output, then the trail can be processed by:

- another Extract (called **Data Pump**) to transfer the trail files to another location
- a replicat Process - to apply the transactions to a destination

Later on the **Replicat** process can read the trails (produced by Extract) and apply the transactions to:

- a database,
- a JMS Queue or flat file (through GoldenGate for Application Adapters),
- Hadoop, target (through GoldenGate for BigData)

The trail files have internal Oracle proprietary format and can not be produced by non-Oracle programs. You can read their content using the **logdump** program.